# How can I use IMemoryCache in a way which allows me to purge specific parts of the cache on demand?

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-core

I've implemented a simple caching mechanism in an ASP.NET Core web app. This is the method I'm using to check the cache for a specific key and, if not set, call a supplied function and populate the cache with the result:

```
    protected async Task<T> GetOrCreateAsync<T>(string key, Func<Task<T>> factory)
    {
        T value;

        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetPriority(CacheItemPriority.Normal).SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CacheExpirySeconds));
            options.AddExpirationToken(new CancellationChangeToken(CacheHelper.ResetCacheToken.Token));

            value = await factory.Invoke();

            _cache.Set(key, value, options);
        }

        return value;
    }
```

The `_cache` property is an `IMemoryCache`.

Here is my `CacheHelper` class:

```
public class CacheHelper
{
    internal static CancellationTokenSource ResetCacheToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public static void ClearCache()
    {
        if (ResetCacheToken != null && !ResetCacheToken.IsCancellationRequested && ResetCacheToken.Token.CanBeCanceled)
        {
            ResetCacheToken.Cancel();
            ResetCacheToken.Dispose();
        }

        ResetCacheToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
}
```

As you can see, `CacheHelper` provides a static `CancellationTokenSource` property which is used to add an expiration token to every cache item. This allows me to call `CacheHelper.ClearCache()` at any time to completely clear the cache.

What I'd like to do now is add some nuance to this process by defining dependencies for my cached items so I can clear a subset of cache items based on a dependency key. For example, when some data changes, purge any cached objects that depend on that specific data.

I assume I need to add another expiration token to my `MemoryCacheEntryOptions` object using an implementation of `IChangeToken`, but I've been looking and can't find any guidance around this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: One suggestion: instead of implementing all this yourself, why not just rely on a cache provider that includes this functionality out of the box. For instance, you could use something like Redis, which is an in-memory store, anyways, but supports many of these more advanced caching scenarios.

Comment: Bringing in an external service with it's own infrastructure isn't a solution to "removing items from cache by pattern".

Answer (score 4):

In your example there's a single CancellationTokenSource on the helper class, but you should have a distinct CancellationTokenSource for each possible 'parent' cache item.

To ensure each cached item has its own CancellationTokenSource  I would create the class:

```
public class CacheItem<T>
{
    public CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; } 
}
```

and adapt GetOrCreateAsync along these lines:

```
 protected async Task<CacheItem<T>> GetOrCreateAsync<T>(string key, Func<Task<T>> factory, params CancellationTokenSource[] dependencies)
    {
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out CacheItem<T> cacheItem))
        {
            //create a new token when creating our new object
            cacheItem.CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cacheItem.Value = await factory.Invoke();

            var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetPriority(CacheItemPriority.Normal).SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(CacheExpirySeconds));

            //ensure that cancelling the token removes this cacheItem from the cache
            options.AddExpirationToken(new CancellationChangeToken(cacheItem.CancellationTokenSource));

            //for globally clearing all cache items
            options.AddExpirationToken(new CancellationChangeToken(CacheHelper.ResetCacheToken.Token));

            //ensure that when this item is expired, any objects depending on the token are also expired
            options.RegisterPostEvictionCallback((object callbackKey, object callbackValue, EvictionReason reason, object state) =>
            {
                (callbackValue as CacheItem<T>).CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            });

            _cache.Set(key, cacheItem, options);
        }

        //the return value provides both the object you wanted to store and a token to be used for any 'child' dependencies. 
        return cacheItem;
    }
```

Now you are able to take the CancellationTokenSource from a returned CacheItem and use it as a dependency param when creating a 'child' cacheItem.